# jQuery Animate: Callback Called Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, velocity.js

I'm triggering a set of animations when an user scrolls down on a website (using afterMove callback from [onepage-scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)) and, when animating some elements, unexpectedly, the same function is called multiple times.

Using this, I don't have a problem:

```
base = $('section[data-index="' + index + '"]');
base.find('h1').animate({opacity: 0.1}, 3000);
console.log('Finished #' + index);
```

And I have the correct output on console after moving to section #3.

```
Finished #2
Finished #3
```

But when I try to use a form, for instance,

```
base.find('#my-form-id').animate({opacity: 0.1}, 3000);
```

this is the output:

```
Finished #2
Finished #3
Finished #2
Finished #3
```

The last two logs are registered only when the animation ends.

What's resulting this behaviour?

Comment: You should post the code showing how you "try to use a form"

Comment: @thanksd You're right, I should've clarified.

Comment: You should also post your function and event calls, since those are where the issue will most likely be

Comment: Can you share your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was searching in the wrong place.

The real problem was that I was styling the element with a CSS3 opacity transition. When I tried to apply any other action to the same element which would use the same attributes, I had this issue.

It seems that they doesn't play nicely together.